# validate first of multiple text boxes

Tags: jquery

I need to validate only first text box, among multiple text-boxes, which share a common name

Example

```
<input type="text" name="value[]" />
<input type="text" name="value[]" />
<input type="text" name="value[]" />
```

How can I validate only first text box, using jQuery? I am using jQuery Validation Plugin

My jQuery code is like, but it's not working

```
rules: {
        name:"required",
        "value[]":"required",
    },
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be nice if you add `required` class to your first textbox only rather defining a rule for validation.

`<input type="text" class="required" name="value[]" />

<input type="text" name="value[]" />

<input type="text" name="value[]" />`

Comment: is it possible to add multiple class like required, number?

Comment: Check boxes do not allow user defined values to be entered. So one may never need to validate a check box's value to be numeric or something like that because these values were already written there by you only ...